# Resizing line icon in Sketch App leads to lines disappearing at a smaller size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app

I'm having a problem with a line icon symbol losing detail on resize.

I have a line icon that was created in illustrator that I copied over to Sketch. I made this line icon a symbol following the steps I have used in the past. Then when I apply this symbol to a page and try to resize it the line detail inside the icon disappears at a smaller size.

I think it has something to do with how it was created in Adobe Illustrator and maybe related to the pixel grid? The only solution I can figure out is recreating it in Sketch from scratch. I have a lot of icons to import in and I don't want to spend the time painstakingly re-creating each one. But this looks like the only option right now.

Anyone else run into this issue and found a work around?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sketch vector lines don't scale](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114899/sketch-vector-lines-dont-scale)

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it.

The issue is most probably with the lines in your icon. When you're resizing the symbol in Sketch, it's not scaling the stroke width, so you end up with a huge stroke on a tiny icon, and then trouble happens.

What you can do is - convert all lines to outlines. To do that - select each line and use Layer/Convert to Outlines.

[image: using convert to outlines]

This way, when scaling, Sketch will behave. I am also attaching a Sketch file with the difference I'm getting. [Sketch file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNghcMK4A5Jb1ZVaVFTendwSjg)

A screenshot:

[image: difference between lines and outlines]